# requirejs - Getting an error loading last module in define array([])

Tags: requirejs, datetimepicker, requirejs-define

I have been experiencing an error to load the last module in define array.

Ex:

```
define(['jquery', 'js/custom','moment','bootstrap','datetimepicker'], function ($, custom) {
     $('#input_start_date').datetimepicker({});
));

Getting an error:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

define(['jquery', 'js/custom', 'chart'], function ($, custom) { 
     var barChart = new Chart(BARCHART_RegistrantComparison, {});
});
Getting an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Chart is not a function

define(['jquery', 'js/custom', 'bootstrap', 'mCustomScrollbar'], function ($, c) {
    $("nav.side-navbar").mCustomScrollbar({
        scrollInertia: 200
    });
});
Getting an error:
Uncaught TypeError: $(...)mCustomScrollbar is not a function
```

I have tried to setup defines via chain of requires but that didn't resolve the problem.

Ex:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    require(['js/custom'], function(c) {
        require(['bootstrap'], function () {
            require(['mCustomScrollbar'], function () {});
        });
    });
});
```

**Below is my require.js configuration.**

```
var require = {
        baseUrl: '/jsp/assets',
        deps:['jquery','js/main'],
        waitSeconds: 50,
        enforceDefine : false,
        paths: {
            "jquery": ['vendor/jquery/jquery.min'],
            "jqueryUI": ['js/jquery-ui.min'],
            "bootstrap": ['vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min'],
            "moment": ['vendor/moment/min/moment.min'], 
            "datetimepicker": ['js/external/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min'],
            "chart" : ['vendor/chart.js/Chart.min'],
            "mCustomScrollbar" : ['vendor/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min']
        },
        shim: {
            "jquery": {exports: ['$', 'jQuery']},
            "jqueryUI": {
                exports: '$',
                "deps": ['jquery']
            },
            "bootstrap": {
                "deps": ['jquery']
            },
            "mCustomScrollbar": {
                exports: 'mCustomScrollbar',
                "deps": ['jquery']
            },
            "chart" : {
                "deps": ['jquery']
            },
            "datetimepicker": {
                "deps": ['moment','bootstrap']
            }
        },
        urlArgs: "1.0"
    };
```

Anybody faced similar issue or have any suggestion, that will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: check the path is correct and remove [] i . e             "jquery":'vendor/jquery/jquery.min',